# Calendar Field render error "Double timezone specification"

Tags: joomla-3.x, form-fields-types, calendar

in my custom component I have a calendar field which I render in my view.

**Database field :**

**Name:** estEventDate
**Type:** date
**Null:** No
**Default:** 0000-00-00

**XML Field :**

```
<field name="estEventDate" type="calendar"   
  format="%Y-%m-%d"
  todaybutton="false"
  filltable="false"
  showtime="false"
  size="22"
  class="validate-dates uk-input"
  minyear="0"/>
```

**The php file tmpl/default.php**

```
<div>
  <?php echo $this->form->renderField('estEventDate'); ?>
</div>
```

**The erros is :**
0 DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (-1-11-30) at position 5 (-): Double timezone specification

And in the log I get this :

```
error   Uncaught \Throwable of type Exception thrown. Stack trace: 
#0 /home/mike/joomla/libraries/src/Date/Date.php(112): DateTime->__construct('-1-11-30', Object(DateTimeZone))
#1 /home/mike/joomla/libraries/src/Factory.php(548): Joomla\CMS\Date\Date->__construct('-1-11-30', Object(DateTimeZone))
#2 /home/mike/joomla/libraries/joomla/form/fields/calendar.php(238): Joomla\CMS\Factory::getDate('-1-11-30', 'UTC')
#3 /home/mike/joomla/libraries/src/Form/FormField.php(975): JFormFieldCalendar->getInput()
#4 /home/mike/joomla/libraries/src/Form/Form.php(670): Joomla\CMS\Form\FormField->renderField(Array)
#5 /home/mike/joomla/components/com_contract/views/contract/tmpl/edit_admin.php(95): Joomla\CMS\Form\Form->renderField('estEventDate')
```

I have tried different options in the xml. (like format,translateformat etc) 
I also have set a date directly in the database (I thought that mayby '0000-00-00' value was the problem)

Joomla v. 3.9.0 / php 7.2

Comment: A similar error with some insight regarding multiple date type fields... https://www.joomlaworks.net/forum/k2-en/48619-datetime-__construct-failed-to-parse-time-string-1-11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be, simply change the database field to varchar or text for saving this form field and then the error should be gone. Then you can get back the string format date values from the database when you need them and you can create any date/datetime format output from the string date that you get from the database. I suggest this, since with the form field rendering does not have any problem basically as I see. And I also dare to suggest this since at plugin params (in extensions table) usually the date fields are also saved in text database fields and that's not a big problem in Joomla. And finally this way you can also spot out in the database date string if the saved date format is not a valid date format. Thus you can repair.

Or, staying at date or datetime field in database, from the xml field definition I would delete the format="%Y-%m-%d" attribute definition, since that might also cause this error (I'll will also check this in my forms).

**A SHORT UPDATE TOWARD FINDING THE REAL CAUSE OF THIS PROBLEM** (just for later researchers)

@mixahlos found the final solution for his above detailed problem, however for me it still remained a bit unclear what caused the wrong date format in the first place. Some important points summarized and a kind of check list on this question/problem:

**1.** The date field is actually a simple text field at input with a calendar input helper.

**2.** The same problem appeared in K2 component a bit more than a year ago, which was caused by an outdated javascript calendar input code used in K2. That caused conflict at the date input. In this particular case this was not the problem.

**3.** @mixahlos traced back the problem with creating the same Form with the same date Fields in a clear Joomla install where he spotted the basic date formatting problem when he tried to get back the date field data from the database. Then in his code he unset the unneeded data in his PHP code (in a custom Joomla controller) and that solved the initial problem. Thus he can now save the dates without problem into date type database fields.

I hope this can help a bit people later with similar problems. At least with few approaches on handling this problem.

Comment: While this may solve the issue, I find it to be suboptimal advice because saving date data as anything other than date type in the database is not best practice.  It would be better to solve the issue than to work around it.

Comment: Well before I see your post, I changed the database field from "date" to "datetime". I didn't change the anything else in my files -except some if ( value = '0000-00-00') statements- And it worked. I guess the calendar field needs datetime even if no time is used.

Comment: @mickmackusa - yes, you are right, that is definitely not an optimal solution if anyone is saving date as text (string), except if the date format is absolutely sure that it is in valid date or datetime format. I agree on this.

Comment: @mixahlos - at least the problem is solved now :) (you can still check that further though one time, since it should work with date type database fields too).

Comment: @Zollie I did changed it back and I noticed that when db field type is date, then the rendered field instead of being empty it displays "-1-11-30" which when page is  loaded is replaced with "2018-01-11". Inspecting the element I see the following attributes in the element : value="-1-11-30" data-local-value="2018-01-11", When field is DateTime the field is blank and in the element attribute the "value"  is empty and there is an attribute data-alt-value="0000-00-00 00:00:00".
I am not sure if makes any difference but I have 3 more Calendar fields in the form of type "DateTime"

Comment: @mixahlos - I placed exactly your xml calendar field into two of my xml based forms, and I do not get any problem when I am saving the dates in the database as date. And I get the date back nicely without any problem. The database field type, I think, does not have anything to do with the problem you wrote about.

Comment: I am not sure what is causing "-1-11-30" for you. When I clear the form, it shows nicely clear values: <input type="text" id="jform_arrival_date" name="jform[arrival_date]" value="" size="40" class="validate-dates uk-input" data-alt-value="0000-00-00 00:00:00" autocomplete="off"> The Calendar field is basically just another text input field.with a comfortable calendar input helper.

Comment: And in one of my plugin form the field looks like this in html: <input type="text" id="jform_params_estEventDate" name="jform[params][estEventDate]" value="2018-12-26" size="22" class="validate-dates uk-input" data-alt-value="2018-12-26" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="false">

Comment: Just for an extra try: in your database table try to let the date field to be NULL and do not define default value for that. Just field name and field type: date.

Comment: I tried NULL in mysql with the same result. I have one other calendar field before that which I also changed type from DateTime to Date and behaves exactly the same way. I tried breeze template (This is in frontend), In the xml, I removed  format, classes, translateformat. Html result is :
<input type="text" id="jform_estEventDate" name="jform[estEventDate]" value="-1-11-30" size="22" class="validate-dates uk-input" data-alt-value="2018-01-11" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="false" data-local-value="2018-01-11">

Comment: @mixahlos - in the calendar input field, the class="validate-dates uk-input" does not ignite a jquery or any other javascript code which can cause interference in this input field at you? Change the field class name to something else and also try it that way too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86485/discussion-between-mixahlos-and-zollie).

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem. Upon analyzing, I found that in my install.mysql.utf8.sql file, I had the following:

```
`dateofbirth` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

Where as the date field in the database only needs dates, not minutes.. sec. etc as mentioned above.

Issue was fixed after I updated the entry in my install file as mentioned below:

```
`dateofbirth` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00'
```

Comment: After almost 3 years of membership, it is great to see you make your first post.  Cheers!

Comment: Thanks @mickmackusa ! have been delving into the Joomla realm since sometime to learn. Would love to contribute more as my learning grows.